# How to export overlapped GRanges object as new bed file in R?

Tags: r

I have used findOverlaps(bed.1, bed.2) to get overlapped regions, now I want to export the result into new bed files such as "xx.bed". How can I do that in R ?

```
overlapped GRanges object with 6 ranges and 3 metadata columns: (example)

      seqnames           ranges strand |         name     score    pvalue
         <Rle>        <IRanges>  <Rle> |  <character> <numeric> <numeric>
  [1]     chr1 [ 32726,  32784]      * |  MACS_peak_7      2.06 0.3138672
  [2]     chr1 [ 52473,  52531]      * | MACS_peak_11      2.06 0.3138672
  [3]     chr1 [136387, 136469]      * | MACS_peak_32      3.40 0.5314789
  [4]     chr1 [235352, 235410]      * | MACS_peak_41      2.06 0.3138672
  [5]     chr1 [540756, 540833]      * | MACS_peak_71      6.42 0.8075350
  [6]     chr1 [636637, 636718]      * | MACS_peak_90      4.86 0.6866363
```

Now I want to export these into new bed files. Which R function can do this ? Is there any simple R code to do this? Thanks

Comment: You can find an answer on biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/89341/

Comment: @Jimbou: it is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's generate appropriate reproducible example above case:

```
foo <- GRanges(
  seqnames=Rle(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4"), c(5, 6, 4, 3)),
  ranges=IRanges(seq(1, by=9, len=18), seq(6, by=9, len=18)),
  rangeName=letters[seq(1:18)], score=sample(1:25, 18, replace = FALSE))
```

then, foo is the object going to be exported as bed format files:

```
write.table(foo, "res.bed", append = TRUE, sep = "")
```

or using export.bed from rtracklayer packages instead, both are yield same results:

```
rtracklayer::export.bed(foo, "~/res.bed")
```